# Creating a class in JSON.NET to deserialize a given JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need an example how of to build a class for a JSON response with JSON.NET.

I am calling the following, that requires a class `ResponseCall` that I have to build:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseCall>(result);
```

My problem is that I am not sure what exactly are all the nested attributes in a class.  What is "responseHeader" and the nested attributes "Status" and how do I access them?

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1801,
    "params": {
      "fl": "id_tlc,ccZzcucbez_tlc,ekonr_tlc,gtin_tlc,region_tlc",
      "sort": "ccZzcucbez_tlc asc",
      "indent": "on",
      "start": "0",
      "q": "indexName:b2cLMIVProdukteIndex AND ( (id_tlc:*000006757 OR    gtin_tlc:6757 OR (addGtin_tlc:6757,* OR addGtin_tlc:*,6757,* OR addGtin_tlc:*,6757 ) OR ekonr_tlc:6757))",
      "wt": "json",
      "qt": "",
      "hl": "true",
      "fq": "",
      "version": "2.2",
      "rows": "10"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "ekonr_tlc": "1030860",
        "region_tlc": "NBST",
        "ccZzcucbez_tlc": "GT EHG ERDINGER WEISSB.DKL.20X0,5L",
        "id_tlc": "NBST_000000000135459003",
        "gtin_tlc": "4002103010036"
      }
    ]
  },
  "highlighting": {
    "b2cLMIVProdukteIndex_NBST_000000000135459003": {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the json on the clipboard then **Edit** -> **Paste Special** --> **Paste JSON as Class**

Comment: The class it generates is pretty much garbage. Things like params and docs look like they should be dictionaries.

Comment: When i am using a dynamic type, how can i ask for the docs-count? How do i ask when docs is empty?

Comment: I second @Plutonix's suggestion. That, and you can also copy/paste to http://json2csharp.com -- you might get some weird looking results, but it is easy to translate the types to something more meaningful most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this class structure:

```
class ResponseCall
{
    [JsonProperty("responseHeader")]
    public ResponseHeader ResponseHeader { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("highlighting")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Highlighting { get; set; }
}

class ResponseHeader
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("QTime")]
    public int QTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Params { get; set; }
}

class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("numFound")]
    public int NumFound { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start")]
    public int Start { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("docs")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Docs { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
ResponseCall rc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseCall>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FdQu7U